# Nested form can't mass assign, create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, has-many, belongs-to

I had to add the pen attributes to the paper model to stop the error "can't mass assign :pen", even thought I had the attr_accessible for pen_attributes.

Now, I'm getting a "unknown attribute: pen" error. It's pointing me to the second line of the create action. I can't figure it out.

I basically want to have to have the Paper New action create the pen and assign it to the paper.

```
Paper model

attr_accessible  :name, :size, :line, 
                    :pen_attributes,
                        :pen, :colour, :style

has_many :pens
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pens
```

---

```
Pens model

attr_accessible :name, :size, :line, :paper_attributes, :paper_id

belongs_to :paper
```

---

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @paper do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :size, :placeholder => "text" %>
        <%= f.input :line %>

            <%= f.fields_for @pen do |h| %>
            <%= h.input :pen,  %>
            <%= h.input :colour %>
            <%= h.button :submit, :label => "create" %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

---

```
Paper Controller


  def new
    @user = current_user
    @paper = @user.paper.build(params[:paper])
            @pen = Pen.new(params[:pen])
  end
```

---

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @paper = @user.papers.build(params[:paper])
    @pen = @paper.pens.build(params[:pen])


    if @paper.save
        flash[:notice] = "#{@paper.name} Created"
        redirect_to(:action => "index")
    else
        flash.now[:notice] = "Error"
        render 'new'    
    end
  end
```

---

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Z8vncB9ewDM1bWiKfsPHOGlkxcGpfhPjv0xpamudIIs=",
 "paper"=>{"name"=>"three",
 "size"=>"three",
 "colour"=>"red",
 "pen"=>{"colour"=>"test",
 "pen"=>"test"}},
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some minor discrepancies in your singular/plural naming.

I think you need to adjust the following:

```
<%= f.fields_for :pens, @pen do |h| %>
```

and probably:

```
attr_accessible :pens_attributes
```

as well as (possibly):

```
 params[:pens]
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that helped fix something. Now when I try it, it's telling me the pen attributes can't be blank. Any idea?

Comment: Did you make sure to change all references to params[:pen] to params[:pens], in your controller? (Assuming that that is one of the adjustments you  had to make, in the view...)